# Problem compiling autoconf

Tags: compiling, autoconf, m4

I am experiencing problems with compiling autoconf and they probably are related to the version of the M4 that I am using. I will put part of the result of running both ./configure as running ./make so someone can confirm is the cause is really that and what I should do to fix it (probably moving to another version of it). If someone wants the full output of any, I will put i.

The M4 version is 1.4.10 and the autoconf is 2.64.

> ./configure --prefix=/media/34GB/Arquivos-de-Programas-Linux/Autoconf-2.64/ --exec-prefix=/media/34GB/Arquivos-de-Programas-Linux/Autoconf-2.64/
>
> checking for GNU M4 that supports accurate traces... /usr/local/bin/m4
>
> checking whether /usr/local/bin/m4 accepts --gnu... no
>
> configure: WARNING: The version of M4 that was found does not support -g.
>
> configure: WARNING: Using it with POSIXLY_CORRECT set may cause problems.
>
> checking how m4 supports trace files... --debugfile
>
> make
>
> make[3]: Entering directory `/media/34GB/Arquivos-de-Programas-Linux/autoconf-2.64/lib/m4sugar'
>   :;{ \
>         echo '# This file is part of -*- Autoconf -*-.' && \
>         echo '# Version of Autoconf.' && \
>         echo '# Copyright (C) 1999, 2000, 2001, 2002, 2006, 2007, 2009' && \
>         echo '# Free Software Foundation, Inc.' && \
>         echo  &&\
>         echo 'm4_define([m4_PACKAGE_NAME],      [GNU Autoconf])' && \
>         echo 'm4_define([m4_PACKAGE_TARNAME],   [autoconf])' && \
>         echo 'm4_define([m4_PACKAGE_VERSION],   [2.64])' && \
>         echo 'm4_define([m4_PACKAGE_STRING],    [GNU Autoconf 2.64])' && \
>         echo 'm4_define([m4_PACKAGE_BUGREPORT], [bug-autoconf@gnu.org])' && \
>         echo 'm4_define([m4_PACKAGE_URL],       [http://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/])' && \
>         echo 'm4_define([m4_PACKAGE_YEAR],      ['`sed 's/^([0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]).*/\1/;q' ../../ChangeLog`'])'; \
>       } > version.m4-t
>   mv version.m4-t version.m4
>   make[3]: Leaving directory`/media/34GB/Arquivos-de-Programas-Linux/autoconf-2.64/lib/m4sugar'
>   autom4te_perllibdir='..'/lib AUTOM4TE_CFG='../lib/autom4te.cfg'         ../bin/autom4te -B '..'/lib -B '..'/lib         --language M4sh --cache '' --melt ./autoconf.as -o autoconf.in*
>    %n in writable segment detected 
>   *Aborted
>   autom4te: /usr/local/bin/m4 failed with exit status: 134
>   make[2]:*  [autoconf.in] Error 134
>   make[2]: Leaving directory `/media/34GB/Arquivos-de-Programas-Linux/autoconf-2.64/bin'
>   make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
>   make[1]: Leaving directory`/media/34GB/Arquivos-de-Programas-Linux/autoconf-2.64'
>   make: * [all] Error 2